# sending parameters as JSON in POST body using spray

Tags: json, scala, akka, spray, spray-json

Ok this is really bugging me.I have implemented a REST api using spray and scala,akka. I have successfully implemented spray get, post routes to query mysql database and give the json output.I am able to send the parameters within the post body but however I am not able to send the same as JSON. Its looks very simple but its just not working.I am getting error - empty reply from server. Please Please help.

Here is my sample curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  -d '{ "name": "Jane", "favNumber" : 42 }' http://localhost:8080/jsonTesting
```

I am trying this small sample code to see if it is possible to unmarshall json parameters and get the required output. If it works then I am implementing the same in my actual code.

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.json._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport

 object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
  implicit val Format = jsonFormat2(Person)

  case class Person(name:String, favNumber:Int)

 //Spray main class
  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp
  import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
  import spray.json._
  import spray.http.MediaTypes._
  import MyJsonProtocol._
  import spray.routing._

   object SprayTest extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    def testRoute(route: Route): Route = {
     post {
      respondWithMediaType(`application/json`){
        route      
        }
      }
     }
   startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {  
   testRoute {
     path("departed") {
       parameter('count.as[Boolean]) {count =>
          complete(if (count == true) "even ball" else "odd ball")
       }
     }
   } ~
   path("jsonTesting") {
     post{
    entity(as[Person]) { person =>
    complete(s"Person: ${person.name} - favoritenumber:${person.favNumber}")
         }
        }
       }
 }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[default]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: spray.json.JsonParser$.apply(Ljava/lang/String;)Lspray/json/JsValue;
at spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonUnmarshaller$1.applyOrElse(SprayJsonSupport.scala:36)
at spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonUnmarshaller$1.applyOrElse(SprayJsonSupport.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller$$anon$1$$anonfun$unmarshal$1.apply(Unmarshaller.scala:29)
at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.SimpleUnmarshaller.protect(SimpleUnmarshaller.scala:40)
at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller$$anon$1.unmarshal(Unmarshaller.scala:29)
at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.SimpleUnmarshaller.apply(SimpleUnmarshaller.scala:29)
at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.SimpleUnmarshaller.apply(SimpleUnmarshaller.scala:23)
at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$3.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:35)
```

Sbt dependecies:

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-experimental" % "0.7",
"io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2",
"io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % sprayVersion,
"io.spray" %% "spray-client" % sprayVersion,
"io.spray" %% "spray-testkit" % sprayVersion % "test",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2"
)
```

Comment: Is the empty reply all that happens? What's the status code? Are there any log messages?

Comment: Sorry @jrudolph for the late reply, I didnt have access to the system for the few days.

Comment: Whenever I get `NoSuchMethodError`s within a library, I double-check my dependencies. It's possible that you have conflicting versions of Spray-Json in your project (perhaps one of them is a transitive dependency). For debugging this kind of problem, [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) is very useful.

Comment: I use sbt for building. I dont see any conflicting versions of spray-json. I have added my sbt dependencies.